# Have TimelineLite only play once on Gatsby site

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gsap, reach-router

I have a `TimelineLite` timeline set up on my Gatsby site to animate my `hero` section when a user navigates to a page. However, if a user clicks a link to the current page i.e. if a user is on the homepage and clicks a link to the homepage, it is reloading the page and triggering the timeline to run again. Is there a way to make sure that my current link will be inactive within Gatsby?

**Hero.tsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import css from 'classnames';
import { ArrowButton } from 'components/arrow-button/ArrowButton';
import { HeadingReveal } from 'components/heading-reveal/HeadingReveal';
import { gsap, Power2, TimelineLite } from 'gsap';
import { RichText } from 'prismic-reactjs';
import htmlSerializer from 'utils/htmlSerializer';
import { linkResolver } from 'utils/linkResolver';

import s from './Hero.scss';

gsap.registerPlugin(TimelineLite, Power2);

export const Hero = ({ slice }: any) => {
  const linkType = slice.primary.link._linkType;
  const buttonLink =
    linkType === 'Link.document' ? slice.primary.link._meta : slice.primary.link.url;

  const theme = slice.primary.theme;
  const image = slice.primary.image;

  const contentRef = useRef(null);
  const headingRef = useRef(null);
  const copyRef = useRef(null);
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);

  const [tl] = useState(new TimelineLite({ delay: 0.5 }));

  useEffect(() => {
    tl.to(contentRef.current, { css: { visibility: 'visible' }, duration: 0 })
      .from(headingRef.current, { y: 65, ease: Power2.easeOut, duration: 1 })
      .from(copyRef.current, { opacity: 0, y: 20, ease: Power2.easeOut, duration: 1 }, 0.5)
      .from(buttonRef.current, { opacity: 0, y: 10, ease: Power2.easeOut, duration: 1 }, 1);
  }, [tl]);

  return (
    <div
      className={css(s.hero, s[theme])}
      style={{
        background: image ? `url(${image.url})` : 'white',
      }}
    >
      <div className={s.hero__container}>
        <div className={s.content__left} ref={contentRef}>
          <HeadingReveal tag="h1" headingRef={headingRef}>
            {RichText.asText(slice.primary.heading)}
          </HeadingReveal>

          <div className={s.content__copy} ref={copyRef}>
            {RichText.render(slice.primary.copy, linkResolver, htmlSerializer)}
          </div>
          <div className={s.content__button} ref={buttonRef}>
            <ArrowButton href={buttonLink}>{slice.primary.button_label}</ArrowButton>
          </div>
        </div>
  
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the built-in `<Link>` component to make that navigation that shouldn't happen since the `@reach/router` doesn't trigger and doesn't re-renders when navigating on the same page. There isn't any rehydration there.

If you are using an anchor (`<a>`) you are refreshing the full page so all your components will be triggered again.

In addition, another workaround that may do the trick in your case is to use a `useEffect` with empty deps (`[]`), creating a `componentDidMount` effect. In that case, since the page is not reloaded, it won't be triggered again:

```
  const [tl] = useState(new TimelineLite({ delay: 0.5 }));

  useEffect(() => {
    tl.to(contentRef.current, { css: { visibility: 'visible' }, duration: 0 })
      .from(headingRef.current, { y: 65, ease: Power2.easeOut, duration: 1 })
      .from(copyRef.current, { opacity: 0, y: 20, ease: Power2.easeOut, duration: 1 }, 0.5)
      .from(buttonRef.current, { opacity: 0, y: 10, ease: Power2.easeOut, duration: 1 }, 1);
    return () => unmountFunction() // unmount to avoid infinite triggers
  }, []);
```

*Note: you may need to make another few adjustments to make the code work since I don't know your requirements. The idea is to remove the dependency of the `t1` to bypass the issue.*

To avoid infinite triggers you may also need to unmount the component with   `return () => unmountFunction()`.

Comment: Thanks, Ferran, you come through with lots of answers! I am using the built in `<Link>` component, which is what baffled me a bit. I’ll give this a try tomorrow, and try and do more digging into why the `<Link>` isn’t working.

Comment: So, it seems like the problem is just with the `useEffect` it's running multiple times. If I remove the timeline from the component then it isn't reloading. I've tried removing `tl` as a dependency for the `useEffect`, but it still is running the code on every click.

Comment: Hi again, Ferran! So, I'm still running into this same problem, and even removing `tl` from the dependency array isn't working; it's running on each click. Do you have any other suggestions, or resources that I should check out?

Comment: My guess is to unmount the `useEffect` but I'm not sure how to handle it with GSAP. https://github.com/hzdg/gsap-react-plugin/issues/6